# In Finnish folklore is there a single firefox or many?

Tags: folklore

In the folklore of northern and eastern Finland, the firefox (tuliko, tulikettu, or tulirepo) is a fox with a tail that twinkles fire. Hunters are said to dream of the firefox, and the northern lights can be called "fox fires" (revontulet) after it.

Is there only a single firefox, as with the phoenix?